# Date toLocaleDateString in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I use `toLocaleDateString` in browser it returns

```
n = new Date()
n.toLocaleDateString()
"2/10/2013"
```

but in node.js the format is completely different

```
n = new Date()
> n.toLocaleDateString()
'Sunday, February 10, 2013'
```

How to get the browser's format (`mm/dd/yy`) in node.js?

Answer (score -19, accepted):

```
Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString = function () {
  var d = new Date();
  return (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
};
```

Comment: If your only solution is to overwrite the prototype, you should probably just write a custom format translation method instead.

Answer (score 22):

For me, the solution was to install an additional module `full-icu` for `node js`
[full-icu-npm](https://github.com/unicode-org/full-icu-npm)

And after in package.json insert:

```
{"scripts":{"start":"node --icu-data-dir=node_modules/full-icu YOURAPP.js"}}
```

or

In the current version of Node.js v10.9.0 is [Internationalization Support](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html).
To control how ICU is used in Node.js, you can configure options are available during compilation.
If the `small-icu` option is used you need to provide ICU data at runtime:

- the **NODE_ICU_DATA** environment variable:  `env NODE_ICU_DATA=/some/directory node`
- the **--icu-data-dir** CLI parameter:  `node --icu-data-dir=/some/directory`

Comment: I feel like it is only answer. Is it possible to make configure node globally to find `full-icu` from global modules?

Comment: @Marecky Of course. Method same. In the example there is a module installation globally
`npm install -g full-icu`

Answer (score 12):

I also found this broken in node.JS. For example, in node console, type

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB')
```

it still displays US format. Using Werner's method above, you can override default Date.toLocaleDateString() behavior for your locale:

```
Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString = function () {
    return `${this.getDate()}/${this.getMonth() + 1}/${this.getFullYear()}`;
};
```

**UPDATE: 2021-12-01**
Starting with Node.js v13.0.0, releases are now built with default full-icu support. So this shouldn't be a problem with later releases.

Answer (score -6):

in node.JS you can not get browser's format.
Node.JS runs on Server-side.

You have to do date formatting before displaying it in browser at your client side JS framework.

Comment: That doesn't preclude the server from specifying a default (just as it does with timezones) or from allowing you to specify a locale (the first parameter of `toLocaleDateString`).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work at all on my server (Node 0.10.28). Whatever value I give to `toLocaleDateString`, it still ouputs in American English format...